# A word that combines shock, hurt and indignation

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that combines, shock, indignation and hurt one feels at the sheer callousness of someone's conduct or apathy towards something/someone?

I was **hurt,shocked and appalled** by his callous conduct.

A single word to replace the above feelings. An idiomatic phrase also works, and if there is conclusively no word that encompasses the entire plethora of emotions,it is acceptable.As is a word which is archaic and no longer in use.

If I were to pick any 2 out of the 3 emotions expressed here, I would pick a combination of hurt and appalled.

Comment: Where will it all end? What about contexts where you're ***hurt** and **shocked***, but not ***appalled**?* Or ***shocked** and **appalled***, but not actually ***hurt***. What if the cause was *accidental, unthinking*, as opposed to *deliberately, knowingly callous?*

Comment: I am looking at all three combined, it ends there :), and alright the cause is knowingly careless. Hope this defines the scope better.

Comment: Try *Mortified.*

Comment: Your title says; **indignation, shock** and **hurt**. Then in the body of your question you add a fourth adjective with **appalled**. How can one word carry the meaning of four separate, albeit related ones?

Comment: That is what I am trying ti find out! If the answer is, there is no such word, that is acceptable.

Comment: So you're looking for a single term which is synonymous with four different words. You'd have better luck asking for an idiomatic expression.

Comment: I wish we could have this conversation, somewhere else given the fact that comments have more space than answers :).An idiomatic expression if it fits all,is welcome as does even an archaic word!

Comment: Then please, edit your question and include everything you have so far mentioned. Your question risks being closed.

Comment: I have edited it, however I do not think my question is invalid.

Comment: Does your native language have such a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"***Chagrin***" suits your requirement perfectly.

cha·grin
transitive verb \shə-ˈgrin\
cha·grined cha·grin·ing
Definition of CHAGRIN
:  to vex or unsettle by disappointing or humiliating  .

Comment: I wouldn’t typically see *chagrin* as being necessarily shocking. Disappointment isn’t always a surprise—in fact, *chagrin* almost seems to favor the kind of disappointment where you hoped for better, but didn’t really expect it.

Answer (score 3):

I think "offended" would work, but I'm not sure it captures "shock" very well. Perhaps "horrified" is a bit better? Oooh, or "aghast," which I think conveys a nice combination of shock and horror. With "aghast" the hurt is implied; No one is aghast and pleased at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Aghast. Speechless with jaw-dropping horror at the shattering of decent and reasonable expectation.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We appreciate your input. We also appreciate links to sources where applicable. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think no.

But appalled, dismayed or horrified may be the closest match

appall |əˈpôl|
verb ( -palled , -palling ) [ trans. ] (usu. be appalled)
greatly dismay or horrify : bankers are appalled at the economic incompetence of some officials | [as adj. ] ( appalled) Alison looked at me, appalled.
ORIGIN Middle English : from Old French apalir ‘grow pale,’ from a- (from Latin ad ‘to, at’ ) + palir ‘to pale.’ The original sense was [grow pale,] later [make pale,] hence [dismay, horrify] ( late Middle English ).

Answer (score 0):

*Devastated* or *destroyed*, as well as *disillusioned* by the sound of it; from a psychological standpoint, you have a lot of feelings about what's happened, but underneath all these is hurt or pain. Illusions and expectations have been rent apart, and you are confronted with a ghastly reality which you had not seen before.